# Happy: This is not a keyword

Tags: parsing, haskell, happy

When you write a Happy description, you have to define all possible types of token that can appear. But you can only match against token *types*, not individual token *values*...

This is kind of problematic. Consider, for example, the `data` keyword. According to the Haskell Report, this token is a "reservedid". So my tokeniser recognises it and marks it as such. However, consider the `as` keyword. Now it turns out that this is *not* a reservedid; it's an ordinary varid. It's only special in one context. You can totally declare a normal variable named `as`, and it's fine.

So here's a question: How do I parse `as` specifically?

Initially I didn't really think about it. I just defined a new token type which represents any varid token who's text happens to be `as`.

...and then I spent about 2 hours trying to work out *why the hell* my grammar doesn't actually work. Yeah, it turns out that since this token type overlaps with an existing token type, the declaration order is significant. (!!!) Literally, changing the order of the declarations made the grammar parse perfectly.

But now I'm worried. I fear that `as` will never be matched as a varid and will only ever match as itself. So all the grammar rules that say varid will reject the `as` token — which is completely wrong!

What is the *correct* way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What GHC does in its [`Parser.y`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ghc/ghc/master/compiler/parser/Parser.y) is to define a nonterminal token type `special_id` that lists many of the special non-keywords like `as`, and then define the `tyvarid` and `varid` (nonterminal) tokens to include that as an option besides the terminal `VARID` (and some others, although most of them look to me like they *should* have been put in `special_id` too).

An excerpt:

```
varid :: { Located RdrName }
        : VARID            { sL1 $1 $! mkUnqual varName (getVARID $1) }
        | special_id       { sL1 $1 $! mkUnqual varName (unLoc $1) }
        | 'unsafe'         { sL1 $1 $! mkUnqual varName (fsLit "unsafe") }
        ...

special_id :: { Located FastString }
special_id
        : 'as'                  { sL1 $1 (fsLit "as") }
        | 'qualified'           { sL1 $1 (fsLit "qualified") }
        | 'hiding'              { sL1 $1 (fsLit "hiding") }
        | 'export'              { sL1 $1 (fsLit "export") }
        ...
```